# Calling of move constructor in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I have following code:

```
struct Base
{
    std::vector<int> a;
}

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(Base && rhs):
        Base( std::forward<Base>(rhs))
    {
    }
    //some more fields
}
//...
Base a;
Derived b(std::move(a));
```

Does calling of `Derived` constructor will lead calling of move constructor of `std::vector` that contained in `Base` class?

Comment: Yes, construction process of `Base part` of `Derived object` will invoke implicitly defined move c'tor of Base which will invoke move constructors of all the data members of Base.

Comment: You should use std::move here.  std::forward is for forwarding arguments passed to templated functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [implicitly-defined move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-defined_move_constructor) of `Base` is called, it will perform move on its data member `a`.

> For non-union class types (class and struct), the move constructor performs full member-wise move of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using direct initialization with an xvalue argument.

[LIVE for confirming](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YNu8BqwvqhC8QiVu)